# Mudar Local da Tabela Exportada do Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web usando jsf e primefaces e gostaria de tirar uma dúvida.

Estou usando o `dataExporter` pra exportar um `dataTable` em PDF....estou usando o método `preProcessor` para acrescentar varias coisas ao documento PDF (cabeçalho, rodapé, parágrafos, etc). O problema é que quando exporto o PDF a tabela original exportada aparece no final da pagina....depois de tudo que eu coloquei atraves do método `preProcessor`.

**Dúvidas:**

- É possível colocar essa tabela em outro local do PDF sem ser no final dele? Exemplo, queria colocar no meio do documento entre alguns textos que eu coloquei.
- Tem como "pegar" essa tabela exportada e coloca-la aonde eu quiser no documento?